# React Context TypeError: BlurChangeValue is not iterable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, jsx

I am using in this example **React Context** and **local storage** using React Context I want to get value in another component but get `BlurChangeValue` is not iterable:

[image]

**SideBarBlurChange.jsx**

```
import React, {useState, createContext} from "react";
import {getTrackBackground, Range} from "react-range";

const STEP = 0.1;
const MIN = 0;
const MAX = 100;

export const BlurContext = createContext([]);

export default function SideBarBlurChange(props) {

    const ls = parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem('values'));
    const [values, SetValues] = useState(ls ? [ls] : [50]);

    const SaveChanges = () => {
        localStorage.setItem('values', values);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <BlurContext.Provider value={{
                BlurChangeValue: [values, SetValues],
            }
            }>
                <div
                    style={{
                        display: "flex",
                        justifyContent: "center",
                        flexWrap: "wrap",
                    }}
                    // More jsx
           </BlurContext.Provider>
        </>
    );
}
```

**SideBar.jsx**

```
export default function SideBar(props) {

    const {BlurChangeValue} = React.useContext(BlurContext)
    const [values] = BlurChangeValue;

    return (
        <div className={"headline_sidebar_wrapper"}>
            <article className={`${Blur.glass} ${Blur.up}`}>
                <nav id="sidebar" className="sidebar-wrapper modal">
                    <div style={{backgroundImage: `url(${SideBarBackground})`}}>
                        <div style={{background: SideBarTheme, backdropFilter: `blur(${values})`}}
                             className={`${Blur.SideBar_Page_Content} ${Blur.SideBarContainer}`}>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </article>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I want to use the value `values` inside JSX to get a blur effect, all other contexts work fine, I just deleted them to make it easier to read the code.

Comment: If you tweak your context value to align with how it's consumed does it resolve? `createContext({ BlurChangeValue: [] });` Nothing else sticks out that I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue here is the initial value of `BlurContext`. Try as instead:

```
export const BlurContext = createContext({
   BlurChangeValue: [],
});
```

Read further about [React.createContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext).

Answer (score 0):

you have to destruct the context object in the `SideBar` element first:

```
const {BlurChangeValue} = {...React.useContext(BlurContext)}
```